# How to untar multi-part tar.gz files via Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, gzip, tar, multipart

I have following two files in my home directory in Red Hat Linux 7.9:

```bash
mydir.tar.gz.aa
mydir.tar.gz.ab
```

I am running the following command to extract the contents from these files :

```bash
cat mydir.tar.gz.* | tar xzf -
```

the command does the job and extracts the contents.

The multipart tar was created via the following command:

```bash
tar czf - * | split --bytes=5MB - mydir.tar.gz.
```

I need to `untar` the files via the Ansible playbook.yml. I tried the following pieces of code:

```yaml
---
- name: untar the multipart tar file
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: untar
    ansible.builtin.unarchive:
      src: /home/McFly/mydir.tar.gz.a*
      dest: /home/McFly/
    become: yes
    become_user: root
...
```

```yaml
---
- name: untar the multipart tar file
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: untar
    ansible.builtin.unarchive:
      src: /home/McFly/mydir.tar.gz.aa
      dest: /home/McFly/
    become: yes
    become_user: root
...
```

```yaml
---
- name: untar the multipart tar file
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: untar
    ansible.builtin.shell: cat mydir.tar.gz.* | tar xzf -
    args:
      chdir: /home/McFly/
      executable: /bin/bash
    become: yes
    become_user: root
...
```

None of the above worked.

How can I untar the multipart tar.gz files via the Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 0):

So I posted three pieces of code above and the following piece of code worked for me:

```
---
- name: untar the multipart tar file
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: untar
    ansible.builtin.shell: "cat mydir.tar.gz.* | tar xzf -"
    args:
      chdir: /home/McFly/
      executable: /bin/bash
    become: yes
    become_user: root
...
```

The code is almost the same except for the part:

```
"cat mydir.tar.gz.* | tar xzf -"
```

Previously there were no double quotes, wrapping the whole command in double quotes did the job.

What happening was: the dash (-) at the end of the shell command was not following the yml syntax rules. Escaping that specific dash by wrapping the whole command inside the double quotes made it work fine.

Comment: So it was just a typo. [YAML Syntax - Gotchas](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) "_You should also be aware of `? : -`. In YAML, they are allowed at the beginning of a string if a non-space character follows, but YAML processor implementations differ, so it’s better to use quotes._".

Comment: It never was a typo. The dash at the very end of the command is the part of command.

Comment: But according your own answer "_Previously there were no double quotes, wrapping the whole command in double quotes did the job_" and the documentation [YAML Syntax - Gotchas](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) "_You should also be aware of `? : -`. In YAML, they are allowed at the beginning of a string if a non-space character follows, but YAML processor implementations differ, so it’s better to use quotes._" it looks like that, just a syntax error.

Comment: 1) it is a typo. 2) that would have been clearer if you had provided a [mre] for each try (i.e. the *what I get° part is missing, we just know [°it doesn't work"](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/))

Comment: @Zeitounator,
minimal reproducible example, noted. Thanks.